# Sending Notification b/w devices using OneSignal

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, onesignal

Hello I'm trying to send Push notification between two users A & B of my android app. Using the OneSignal Website is a manual way and I want to send notification via the app itself , say user A Presses a button and a notification is sent to user B.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending custom notification using OneSignal you need to Authorization and notification structure with OneSignal URL may share my code with you.

```
https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
```

Passing these headers

```
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization Basic <your-rest-client-key>
```

set below JSON into your body

```
{
  "app_id": "<your-app-id>",
  "included_segments": ["All"],
  "content_available":"true",
  "data": {"foo": "bar"},
  "contents": {"en": "Test_Message_Body"},
  "headings": {"en": "Test_Message_Title"}
}
```

Comment: thanks got it working , now I just need to figure out how to target a specific user .

Comment: if the answer is valid so please accept because it makes helpful for another one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code from OneSignal official blog to target specific users by using filters. This helped me solve my problem.

```
try {
        String jsonResponse;

        URL url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ZWY0YTU2YTItMjUzMC00NGY3LThiNTQtODFiY2U1NjQ5NmZj");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");


        //////////////////////////////// --> Apply Search Criteria Filters Here <-- /////////////////////////
        String strJsonBody = "{"
                +   "\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\","
                +   "\"filters\": [{\"field\": \"tag\", \"key\": \"" + himID + "\", \"relation\": \"=\", \"value\": " +
                "\"himID\"},{\"operator\": \"OR\"},{\"field\": \"amount_spent\", \"relation\": \">\",\"value\": \"0\"}],"
                +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
                +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"One Signal Notification Test\"}"
                + "}";
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Log.d("Query Check->","  Query Check-> jsonResponse:\n" + strJsonBody);

        byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
        con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(sendBytes);

        int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

        if (  httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
            scanner.close();
        }
        else {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
            jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
            scanner.close();
        }
        Log.d("Query Check->","  Query Check-> jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

    } catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java Code:-
where userId is the unique registration id of reciever

```
try {
                        OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en': '"+ msg_welcome +"'}, 'include_player_ids': ['" + userId + "']}"),
                                new OneSignal.PostNotificationResponseHandler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.i("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Success: " + response.toString());

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(JSONObject response) {
                                        Log.e("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Failure: " + response.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Using PHP :-
where $device_id is the unique registration id of reciever

```
<?PHP
function sendMessage($device_id,$msg_title,$msg_body,$msg_img){
    $content = array(
      "en" => $msg_body
      );
     $heading = array(
      "en" => $msg_title
      );
//  $device_id = "da2e72a0-6af7-4102-819e-4b7db5XXXXXX";
    $include_player_id = array(
        $device_id
      );

    $fields = array(
      'app_id' => "YOUR_APP_ID",
      'contents' => $content,
      'headings' => $heading,
      'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
      'small_icon'=> "ic_launcher",
      'large_icon'=> "ic_launcher",
      'big_picture'=> $msg_img,
      'include_player_ids' => $include_player_id 

      );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                           'Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
  }

   $response = sendMessage();
    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return = json_encode( $return);

  print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
    print($return);
  print("\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have low reputation so I am answering instead commenting.

> thanks got it working , now I just need to figure out how to target a specific user . – Ali Lal Din

On how to target a specific user, you can remove `included_segments` attribute and send `include_player_ids` instead.

Comment: Why not just answer the question, with code and examples and results demonstrating what you are saying here?  Then this would be an answer...